# Uniqueness of the solution of a PDE system

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

If I have the following PDE system:

$\frac{\delta}{\delta t}x(t,r)=-\int_0^1 G(|r-r'|)y(t,r')dr'x(t,r)$

$\frac{\delta}{\delta t}y(t,r)=\int_0^1 G(|r-r'|)y(t,r')dr'x(t,r)-y(t,r)$

$x(0,r)=a(r), y(0,r)=1-a(r)$

where $G:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}$ is $C^\infty$ with compact support.

There exist a teorem for the existence and the uniqueness of the solution $(x(t,r),y(t,r))$ with $(t,r)\in[0,T]\times[0,1]$?

Thank you

Comment: I think you mean the uniqueness of the solution?

Comment: Yes, sorry my english is not so good. Thank you very much